# Showing Bottom Tab Navigator in every single screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

**Background**

Quite simple question, really, I have designed a bottom tab navigator for my app which shows only 5 icons/buttons. I need that nav to show in almost every screen.

**Problem**

This is my app structure:

```
<NavigationContainer> 
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={user ? 'Home' : 'Login'}
    screenOptions={{cardStyle: { backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' }}}> 
    <Stack.Screen name="Home"options={{headerShown: false}}> 
      {props => <TabNav {...props} extraData={user} />} 
    </Stack.Screen> 
    <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} options={{headerShown: false}}/> 
    <Stack.Screen name="RegistrationMethod" component={RegistrationMethod} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
    <Stack.Screen name="TermsScreen" component={TermsScreen}  options={{headerShown: false}}/> 
    <Stack.Screen name="Registration" component={RegistrationScreen}  options={{headerShown: false}}/> 
    <Stack.Screen name="Detail" options={{title: ''}} component={BarDetail}/> 
    <Stack.Screen name="Profile" options={{headerShown: false}}>
      {props => <ProfileScreen {...props} extraData={user} />}
    </Stack.Screen>
    <Stack.Screen name="personalDetails" options={{title: 'Perfil'}}>
      {props => <PersonalDetails {...props} extraData={user} />}
    </Stack.Screen>
    <Stack.Screen name="config" component={ConfigScreen} options={{title:'Configuración'}}/>
    <Stack.Screen name="menu" component={MenuScreen} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
    <Stack.Screen name="checkoutStart" component={checkoutStart} options={{title: 'Tu compra'}}/>
    <Stack.Screen name="checkoutII" component={checkoutII} options={{title: 'Tu compra'}}/>
    <Stack.Screen name="reviewScreen" component={ReviewScreen} options={{title: 'Tu opinión'}}/>
    <Stack.Screen name="searchScreen" component={TabNav} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
  </Stack.Navigator> 
</NavigationContainer>


<Tab.Navigator initialRouteName={user ? 'Home' : 'Login'} tabBarOptions={{showLabel: false}}
    screenOptions={{showLabel: false, cardStyle: { backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' }}} sceneContainerStyle={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({size,focused,color}) => {
              if (focused) {
                return (
                  <SelectedHome/>)
              } else {
                return (
                  <LinearHome/>)
              }
              ;},}}
          >
        {props => <HomeScreen {...props} extraData={user} />} 
      </Tab.Screen> 
      <Tab.Screen name="Fav" component={FavScreen} options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({size,focused,color}) => {
          
                return (
                  <LinearFav/>)
              
              ;},}}
              />
      <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={SearchScreen} options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({size,focused,color}) => {
              if (focused) {
                return (
                  <SelectedSearch/>)
              } else {
                return (
                  <LinearSearch/>)
              }
              ;},}}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({size,focused,color}) => {
              if (focused) {
                return (
                  <SelectedNotifications/>)
              } else {
                return (
                  <LinearNotifications/>)
              }
              ;},}}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="HelpScreen" component={HelpScreen} options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({size,focused,color}) => {
              if (focused) {
                return (
                  <SelectedHelp/>)
              } else {
                return (
                  <LinearHelp/>)
              }
              ;},}}/>
    </Tab.Navigator>
```

So I need the Tab Navigator as it is to show up in most screens from the stack navigator. I thought of changing it up, making it all tab and stack but wouldn't that cause a mess and also show every screen in the footer as touchable?

**Question**

How can I persist the tab navigator with only those icons in every other screen? (Note that the solution should consider that it must be able to be hidden in some specific screens.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show the bottom tab navigator on certain screens then you should put those screens inside a `<Stack.Navigator />` and put the `<Stack.Navigator />` inside `<Tab.Navigator />`.

More details here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation#a-stack-navigator-for-each-tab

Comment: Cool, I'll check that out. If I solve my issue with that doc I'll accept your answer.